# protest one's involvement

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I have seen the phrase "protest one's innocence" before, but I'm wondering whether the verb in this sense can take a different object like "involvement."
Is it correct to say the following?

> You said John had contributed nothing to the project, but he protested his involvement.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: The transitive form *to protest one's innocence* is something of a "fixed phrase", that's not really part of "productive" syntax today. Hence your example usage sounds "strange" and/or "dated" (I've no idea if such usages were in fact common in Victorian times, but they're certainly not today).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is correct to say the above.

Protest is [defined as](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/protest):

> **an expression or declaration of objection, disapproval, or dissent**

In this case, John is objecting that he *contributed nothing to the project* and is trying to convince people that he did contribute to the project.

Comment: Are you a native speaker of English?

Comment: @Apollyon yes I am

Comment: But the way you used "object" as in "John is objecting that he contributed nothing to the project" seems unusual; you meant to say "John is objecting that he did contribute to the project," didn't you?

Comment: Alternatively, you might have wanted to say "John is objecting to the claim that he contributed nothing to the project."